# Ajax - Response from another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

My HTML as follows, located in index.php

```
        <div id="showDetails">
           
        </div>


        <div id="showList">
           
        </div>
```

And my Ajax as follows, still in index.php

```
  function funcReadRecord() {
    var readrecord1 = "readrecord1";
    var sometext = $('#SNOW_INC').val();

    $.ajax({
      url : "findsql.php",
      type : 'post' ,
      data : { readrecord1 : readrecord1,
        sometext : sometext } ,
        success : function(data, status){
          $('#showList').html(data);
        }
      });

    }
```

Now, I can return my list and view the required list (shown as a list group) in index.php.
I have a button in index.php that when clicked, runs the function.

```
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="funcReadRecord()" class="btn btn-primary">Search SQL (LIKE)</button>
</div>
```

The code in findsql.php as follows

```
if(isset($_POST['readrecord1']) && isset($_POST['sometext'])){

  $displaysql = "SELECT * from datadump where short_description LIKE '%".$_POST['sometext']."%'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $displaysql);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

      $items[] = array(
                        "number" => $row['number'],
                        "priority" => $row['priority'],
                        "description" => $row['short_description']);
    }
  }

  echo '<p class="lead">SEARCH SQL (LIKE)<p>';

  echo '<div class="list-group">';
  foreach($items as $result) {
      
  ?>

      <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
      <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <h5 class="mb-1"><?php echo $result['number']; ?></h5>
        <small></small>
      </div>
      <p class="mb-1"><?php echo $result['description']; ?></p>
      <small><?php echo $result['priority']; ?></small>
    </a>

    <?php
  }
  echo '</div>';

}
```

All I'm doing is getting the data from MySQL and assigning them to array and listing them. I know I could do it directly but I need the array in some other function.
The question is how do I make details from the array to show in ***showDetails*** div tag when I click the list? Right now, the HREF is #. I could assign a function, but not sure where to write them.

If I should write a function to return them, should I write in index.php or findsql.php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you need individual record information in **#showDetails** div right ! then
step1: assign new function while clicking the particular item as onclick="funcReadRecord(number)", this should at findsql.php file.
step2: write an ajax function in index.php which will send that particular unique id or in your case **number**

```
function funcReadRecord(number) {
  $.ajax({
   url : "findsql.php",
   type : 'post' ,
  data : { id: number } ,
    success : function(data, status){
      $('#showDetails').html(data);
    }
  });
```

Step3: Write another function in **findsql.php** with else if block as checking id *isset* or not, change the query that takes the *number* or any key that gets only that particular record.

```
else if(isset($_POST['id'])){
   $displaysql = "SELECT * from datadump where number = ".$_POST['id'].";
   // remaining design code below
 }
```

We can use the if-else statement to write multiple ajax calls as above.

**Edited**, Note: kindly ignore the syntax issue in the above code, concentrate on the process used to a single PHP file for multiple ajax calls using branching statements.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: You need to remove the `%` as well. And as stated above, _don't ever write a query that contains user data directly like this_ since it leaves you wide open for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I think I got the idea. I'll try that.